# Swift: How to create an array of date arrays [ [Date] ], after comparing/splitting two date arrays [Date]

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting, date

## Introduction

I'm creating a calendar app and I'm in need of managing of a date array in order to provide data for a `UITableView`.

### Context

The data model is of type `[Date : [CalendarEvent]]`, where `CalendarEvent` is a `NSManagedObject` subclass that I sort into a dictionary grouped on the events associated date attribute. And I have one section for each key of that dictionary in my `UITableView` (I don't fetch all calendar events at once). However I would like to add more sections to display the date interval gaps between dates with events, using an array of type `[[Date]]`

- Clarification: Picture that my calendar app has 2 events stored. One event 2018-12-05 and one event 2018-12-09, and todays date is 2018-12-01. In that case I would like to retrieve an array like the following: `[ [2018-12-01, 2018-12-02, 2018-12-03, 2018-12-04], [2018-12-05], [2018-12-06, 2018-12-07, 2018-12-08], [2018-12-09], [2018-12-10] ]` where each of those dates are of type `Date` of course. (Which would yield in 4 sections)

### Question

- *How do I sort/split my arrays to satisfy the format `[[Date]]` (explained in the "clarification" above)?*

  - If there is a simpler way to achieve the same result, that would also be regarded as an answer.

### My attempt

I've scaled down to only display the necessary parts.

```
class CalendarViewController: UIViewController {
    private let currentCalenar = Calendar.current
    var events : [Date: [CalendarEvent]]? // Events is fetched from todays date and 10 days forward.
    var sectionDates : [[Date]]?

    func getDatesWithEvents() -> [Date]? {
        if let keyArray = events?.keys {
            var dateArray = Array(keyArray)
            dateArray.sort { $0 < $1 }
            return dateArray
        }
        return nil
    }

    func getSectionDatesArray() -> [[Date]]? { 
        var sectionDatesArray : [[Date]] = []
        var currentDate = currentCalendar.startOfDay(for: Date())
        guard let endDate = currentCalendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 9, to: currentDate), let datesWithEvent = getDatesWithEvents() else { return nil }
        while currentDate < endDate {
            if datesWithEvent.contains(currentDate) {
                sectionDatesArray.append([currentDate])
                sectionDatesArray.append([])
            } else {
                if !sectionDatesArray.isEmpty {
                    sectionDatesArray[sectionDatesArray.count - 1].append(currentDate)
                } else {
                    sectionDatesArray.append([currentDate])
                }
            }
            currentDate = currentCalendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: currentDate)!
        }
        sectionDatesArray.removeAll { (sequence) -> Bool in
            sequence.isEmpty
        }
        return sectionDatesArray
   }
```

Thanks for reading my question.

Comment: Arent' your two branches exactly the same? Why don't you use an empty array instead of an optional `dateSections`? Then you could just use `dateSections.append`, or even `map`.

Comment: @Sulthan Thanks for commenting! Thats a valid point since the `dateSection` never will be nil. Ye i just noticed that I copied that over wrong. Embarrassing, i'll edit my question with it, however my actual attempt isn't better. The problem is, however, that I can't figure out how to syntax algorithm correctly, I am apparently not enough of a friend with swift syntax yet. Would you mind showing a quick example of how I could formulate the map method, in an answer? The current answer attempt below leaves some issues.

Comment: Please, add the correct code please. If your code is working, it's possible that https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ would be a better place for it.

Comment: @Sulthan It appears i wrote the comment above a bit hasty on my phone... I've updated my question with my current code. And yes it works for the time being, however Nivs, answer led me to believe it was a bad way of perfoming this algorithm and therefore I would like to learn how to do it effectively / in good practice. If I may consult you: Is that a valid reason for keeping the question open? Or should i use the code review sister site?

Answer (score 0):

In general, using **multiple data sources** on a single **UITableView** brings **bad luck.**.. you might consider changing your data model.

In your example I would consider merging those two data sources in a way that values of dates with no events will be `nil`, so you would declare it as `var dates: [Date: [CalendarEvent]?]?`.

Another way- you would cut off this dictionary and use an array to store objects of type (suggested name) `CalendarItem`- in there you may store the item's `Date` and `[CalendarEvent]?`

Nevertheless there are many ways to do that and I'm not going to cover them all...

If you want to stick with your model, here's a function I've made. It's probably not the optimal solution and there's some magic that can do it in 4 lines :) but here you go-

```
var currentDate = Date()

// just made up dates
let datesWithEvents: [Date] = [
    Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 5, to: currentDate)!,
    Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 10, to: currentDate)!
]

let endDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 15, to: currentDate)!

var dates: [[Date]] = []
while currentDate < endDate{

    if datesWithEvents.contains(currentDate){
        dates.append([currentDate])
        dates.append([])
    }else{

        if !dates.isEmpty{
            dates[dates.count - 1].append(currentDate)
        }else{
            dates.append([currentDate])
        }
    }

    currentDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: currentDate)!
}

/* prints
 [
    [
        2018-12-04 17:57:44 +0000
        2018-12-05 17:57:44 +0000
        2018-12-06 17:57:44 +0000
        2018-12-07 17:57:44 +0000
        2018-12-08 17:57:44 +0000
    ],
        [2018-12-09 17:57:44 +0000],
    [
        2018-12-10 17:57:44 +0000,
        2018-12-11 17:57:44 +0000,
        2018-12-12 17:57:44 +0000,
        2018-12-13 17:57:44 +0000
    ],
        [2018-12-14 17:57:44 +0000],
    [
        2018-12-15 17:57:44 +0000,
        2018-12-16 17:57:44 +0000,
        2018-12-17 17:57:44 +0000,
        2018-12-18 17:57:44 +0000
    ]
 ]
 */
```

Comment: Hello and thanks for your answer! And yes, I'll see if I can change that, it makes sense to have the data model not requiring this amount of sorting. Meanwhile *however* I've implemented your example code and it works perfectly for 2 datesWithEvents but, when I have 3 or more dates-with-events, it returns occasional empty arrays ([[with dates], [with dates], [], [with dates]]etc). It does not happen if the `dates.append([ ])` is deleted, but that will remove some of the non events associated date arrays within `dates`. I have not been able to fix this myself, would you mind having a look?

Comment: Well this problem occurs when dates are a single day apart from each other, it can be solved by replacing the first if statement with this- `if datesWithEvents.contains(currentDate){
        if dates.last! == []{
            dates[dates.count - 1] = [currentDate]
        }else{
            dates.append([currentDate])
        }
        dates.append([])
    }else` but its ugly so I would recommend you to find another method because I don't have enough time :(

Comment: I've added instead a method that removes empty arrays within the array. That seems to make it hold. I'm still interested in better practices / a clean way of doing it. I'll leave this open a bit more and if I get no better answer i'll accept this, since it does indeed work correctly so far. However your other model suggestions seems to need the same amount of sorting logic?